# Can't update TeraWurfl database through Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, wurfl

I'm trying to resume and expand an old web application developed by other people and based on Symfony 1.4.
This web application get some data from TeraWurfl database through sfTeraWurflPlugin (ver. 0.9.9), a plugin that bridges the symfony framework and Tera-wurfl PHP/MySQL API library.

As described in plugin's instructions,I'm trying to update the TeraWurfl database browsing to the application module's default page:

```
http://myproject/frontend_dev.php/sfTeraWurflAdmin
```

The browser shows the following error (generated by the plugin itself):

```
500 | Internal Server Error | Exception
Error in DB RIS Query: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted.
Query: CALL TeraWurfl_RIS('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0',7,'Firefox')
```

I also tried to execute the query directly from MyPhpAdmin and i recieve the following error:

```
PROCEDURE mydatabasename.TeraWurfl_RIS does not exist
```

Any idea how to fix the issue / retrieve the missing procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TeraWurfl_RIS`(IN ua VARCHAR(255), IN tolerance INT, IN matcher VARCHAR(128)
```

taken from [plugin svn repo](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfTeraWurflPlugin/trunk/lib/DatabaseConnectors/TeraWurflDatabase_MySQL5.php)

Comment: The issue was due to an inconsistency in the database. I had to fix my installation of mysql